# How can I post photos to my iPhone Instagram app from Google Drive?

Tags: photos, iphone, google-apps, instagram

I have Instagram and Google Drive both installed on my iPhone. I want to post on Instagram some photos from Google Drive. Have somebody any ideas how to do that, because in Insta library I have only photos from my iPhone camera.

Comment: I don't have Google Drive so I can't test it, but the latest version of Instagram can be added as an "Activity" under the Share menu for photos. Try going to a photo in Google Drive, tap the Share button, scroll right on the Activity icons (the colorful ones), tap More, enable Instagram if it is disabled, tap Done, then select Instagram from the Share menu.

Comment: I understood your idea and have Share button in iCloud photos and native iPhone Photo app. But there is no Share button in Google Drive and Google photos.

Comment: I see, that's the part I wasn't sure about. Is there a reason you don't want to save the photos to your phone then add them to Instagram?

Comment: It was rather comfortable for me to use Google Drive for PC, laptop and Android tablet. Download edited photos to Drive and post them to Insta with a tablet. Now I think I would save photos directly to iPhone as you advise, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To share a photo from your Google Drive to Instagram on your iPhone, you open the photo you want to share (by tapping on it), on the top right you'll see 3 little dots, tap the dots, and you'll get a list of options.  Choose the 'Open in' option and that will give you the option to share with Facebook etc.  if Instagram isn't there, go to the More option and enable it.  Hope that helps - took me ages to work it out!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are specifically asking for how to share from your "Insta library", by which you mean you'd like for photos and videos from Google Drive to behave like they're on your Camera Roll, here is the solution:

1. Press **3 dots** on the photo/video you'd like to post
2. Press **Send a copy**
3. Scroll down, and select either "Save photo" or "Save video"

[image]

Now, when you open Instagram and try to post from your library, the item will show up as though it's in your Camera Roll.

This allows you to use the other options that Instagram offers, such as people or location tagging, cross posting, etc

*[Image source](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-download-videos-from-Google-Drive-on-to-my-camera-roll)*

Answer (score 0):

in gdrive choose the image and in the options menu click send a copy and then open in "copy to Instagram" is a choice

Answer (score 0):

Use “open in” to email it to yourself. Save to phone right from the email, then upload to Instagram from iPhone photos like normal.

The worst part is that you have to email them *one at a time* as it won’t let you use “open in” on more than one item at a time (the option doesn’t even show up if you have multiple items selected).

Good luck!

(This worked for me on 5/27/18)

Edit: I only had to use this method because I had two photos and one video that I wanted to post in the same post. If you only have one item you can use “share item” directly to Instagram, as another person has commented. :)